# Does C# Scripting API support parameter interpolation?

Tags: c#, roslyn

E.g., I have a code snippet like this:

```
string id = {id};
State state = State.observed;
HttpWebResponse response = proxyClient.ChangeState(id, state);
if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    // handling error
}
```

I want to interpolate the `{id}` to a real value in runtime before handing it to `CSharpScript`, I dont want to define a `Global` class to encapsulate all parameters like example code shows, can I do that? Must I wrap the snippet in a C# function? 
My second question is, the `ChangeState` function resides in another assembly, how to tell C# scripting API to load that assembly?

Edit: The story behind this a little odd question is, I am developing a workflow like application, and I want to create an activity class can take a piece of C# code from configuration file and run it, but the code usually need input arguments which values are only determined from parent activity, for now all input arguments are strings.

Comment: Please define what is the "C# scripting API", because there are more than one. Roslyn? CodeDOM?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto OP is referring the Roslyn scripting API. and in fact referring the specific example on [parameterizing scripts](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples#parameter) but apparently they don't want to do it like in the example.

Comment: @mikez Thanks, added the tag to reflect that. Guess I need to dig more into Roslyn :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you'll need is a Lambda that takes in a parameter in this case.

There are two main types you'd want to look into; Action and Func.
Action types do not return any variables, and Func types have return types. You can template them which makes things more flexible.

You can create these at runtime, and edit them to your needs. So if you are in a big loop and you have some function you need to adjust, you can change the input and output as you plod along through it with a simple variable assignment.

---

```
Action<string> idCheckAction = (string _id) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID = " + _id);
};

Func<string, string> idCheckFunc = (string _id) =>
{
    return "ID = " + _id;
};

idCheckAction("123"); // "ID = 123"

string concat = idCheckFunc("123"); 
Console.WriteLine(concat); // "ID = 123"
```

---

Something like this can be used to great effect for console logging, as you can store a list of string values + Action/Func values, and from there call those functions via keyword or iterator.

And on the topic of Assembly loading, I believe a simple `using (X)` would be sufficient. You can check which resources you have by going into visual studio, looking on the right in your solution explorer and checking your references. You can add them directly from file no worries. You'd need to look into how to hotload assemblies, but I think it is do-able with Reflection, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Thanks but what I wanted is the ability to load and run a piece of C# code from text file in runtime. I am developing a workflow like application, and I want to develop an activity class can take a piece of C# code from configuration file and run it, but the code usually need input arguments which values are only determined from parent activity. Forgot to mention that for now all input arguments are strings.